# what is the best way of providing instant search functionality as a user types in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i want the user to search for an employee by Name or Employee number. I have provided then with a textbox. So as the user types in the textbox, i handle the _TextChanged event and  update a dataGridview with a list of employees whose Employee Name or Employee Number contains the text the user is entering in the textbox.

The problem am having is that this slows typing and the the datagridview update because every time text changes in the textbox, my search query hits the database. This makes the form some how un responsive.

Does some one know of a better approach?

Comment: You should try caching the database results in a list. Then pull from the list instead of the database on `_TextChanged`

Comment: I am supporting to this comment

Comment: You could have it search the database only when there's a certain number of characters in the textbox, eg 3. Then as gwin003 suggested, stick those results in a list, and for characters > 3 draw your results from that list. That way if the character backspaces to < 3, it'll only then run another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Simple:** delay querying the db for half a second or second to ensure the user has stopped typing by remembering the last time some text has changed.
- **Better in long term:** If the db query takes a long time (more than a second) then you can outsource querying the db to
  another thread (task or backgroundworker). You can even fill the
  DataGrid in an own Task if it's so much data that drawing takes long. Also you will be able to
  implement some canceling mechanism and you have your main GUI
  elements remain responsive.

I thought about something like in the democode below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication19
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // cancel old query and datagrid update
            tokenSource.Cancel();

            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;

            Task.Factory.StartNew((s) =>
                {
                    var q = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<DemoData>>(() => LongLastingDataQuery(textBox1.Text, token), token);
                    if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => BindData(q.Result));
                }, token);
        }

        private IEnumerable<DemoData> LongLastingDataQuery(string search, CancellationToken token)
        {
            List<DemoData> l = new List<DemoData>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000 * search.Length; i++)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return l;

                l.Add(new DemoData { ID = i, Text = search + i, Text1 = search + i + i, Text2 = search + i + i + i, Text3 = search + i + i + i + i });
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return l;
        }

        private void BindData(IEnumerable<DemoData> enumerable)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
                dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => BindData(enumerable)));
            else
            {
                demoDataBindingSource.DataSource = null;
                demoDataBindingSource.DataSource = enumerable;
            }
        }

        public class DemoData
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public string Text1 { get; set; }
            public string Text2 { get; set; }
            public string Text3 { get; set; }
            public int ID { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added some working demo code to show how to accomplish this with nested tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. Handle the "TextBox enter KeyPressdown" event instead of the TextChange event, so the event is only triggered when the "Return" key is pressed after you typed the query .  Sample code is like this:

   ```
   private void searchTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
       {
           // DoQueryAndRebindEmployees(searchTextBox.Text);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you insist on handling in TextChange event,  put the database search code in another thread, like in a BackgroundWorker thread,
   In the TextChange Event handler:

   ```
    BackgroundWorker employeeQueryWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
       employeeQueryWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(employeeQueryWorker_DoWork);
       employeeQueryWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(employeeQueryWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
       employeeQueryWorker.RunWorkerAsync(searchTextBox.Text);
   ```

To communicate between the Backgroundwork thread and UI thread,   you can define a member variable of the class to represent the employee  query result, like

```
 private IList<Employee>  m_employeeQueryResult = null;
```

then in employeeQueryWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) thread method, perform the time-consuming database query and store the query result into m_employeeQueryResult .

At last, in the employeeQueryWorker_RunWorkerCompleted() method, bind the m_employeeQueryResult with the DataGridView control.

This will keep the UI controls responsive.